# Apache Rewrite Conditions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, url-rewriting

I am currently trying to redirect all frontend pages on a Magento install to a specific page, however when I do this, I can no longer gain access to the Magento back office. I have tried the following, but it doesnt appear to work, it still redirects everything.

Any help would be much appreciated.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/admin/
RewriteRule ^(.*) new-url [R=301,QSA,L]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this as your first rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin/
RewriteRule ^ new-url [R=301,L]
```

Make sure to test in a new browser.

Comment: I have just tried this in a new incognito window, and again no luck

Comment: What exactly is your value for `new-url` and are you still seeing magento admin going to the `new-url`?